# path.join not working in express 3 with node v0.10.41

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to use `less` with Express 3 but I am getting an error

> "TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings"

in node v0.10.41

In my application code:

```
app.use(less({
   src : path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'less'),
   dest : path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'css'),
   prefix : '/css'
}));
```

here is my Package.json

```
{
  "name": "tolga",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.41",
    "npm": "1.4.29"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "~0.2.9",
    "bignum": "~0.6.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.14.2",
    "connect-redis": "~1.4.5",
    "ejs": "*",
    "express": "3.2.6",
    "geolib": "~1.3.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error stems from the use of the `less` module as middleware.

The appropriate approach would be to utilize the [less-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/less-middleware) module. Once installed, you can use the middleware in this manner:

```
// Install the 'less-middleware' module first
var lessMiddleware = require('less-middleware);

// 'less-middleware' takes the source as the first argument.
app.use(lessMiddleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), {
  dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'css'),
  prefix: '/css'
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but i am already installed **less-middleware** module, but it is not working  


var express = require('express')
      , http = require('http')
      , path = require('path')
      , less = require('less-middleware');

Comment: The middleware takes the source as the first argument. Please see the code in the answer.

Comment: Updated my code as above but still getting the same error. It might be because of my node version 0.10.41 and application was built in node v 0.8